# Sonar false positive on assert of Optional.isPresent()

Tags: java, sonarqube, assert

Looks like if sonar doesn't see an exact check of `Optional.isPresent()` in `if` statement, it reports an [issue](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3655). I have the following code:

```java
Optional<String> myOptional = getMyOptional();
assertTrue(myOptional.isPresent());

String stringFound = myOptional.get();
```

So i have a check that `myOptional` is present.If it isn't an `AssertionError` is thrown. This check is done in org.junit.Assert. Anyway sonar doesn't like it or doesn't see it.
Is it a sonar bug? Or what is a proper way to deal with checking `Optional`s?

Comment: It works fine if an "if" condition is added before `.get()`. Agreed that assert should have been fine too.

Comment: try with `assert (myOptional.isPresent());`

Comment: Firstly **Optional** is designed in such a way that if you want to get some value then to overcome exception you have to first check using `isPresent()` then get a value so it's not a bug, it's a rule made to use it.


You can simply get value using:

    `myOptional.ifPresent(someValue -> System.out.println(someValue))`

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixit why should i add additional check? I already have one

Comment: @AmmarAli please, read the question more carefully. I have no problem in understanding Optionals. And i have a ckeck: `isPresent`

Comment: @bdshadow You can replace `myOptional.get()` with `myOptional.orElse("")`.

Comment: [Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018931/anand) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65016591/12695027) saying "Your code is clearly correct. For more details on how this area is treated by SONAR w.r.t false positives, refer: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3043 https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3087"